# Request focus on my second edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

In my XML code I have 2 `EditText`s, the first one for username, the second one for password. I am actually using `SharedPreferences` to always keep username but I want to request focus on my password `EditText`.

I tried adding this to my password `EditText` XML code:

```
<requestFocus></requestFocus>
```

In my OnCreate code:

```
    etUserName.clearFocus();
    etPassword.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    etPassword.requestFocus();
```

The above works, if I also do `etUserName.setFocusable(false);`. It "works" (focus is on the second `EditText`) but I can't change the value of `etUserName` in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the below lines:

```
etUserName.clearFocus();
etPassword.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
etPassword.requestFocus();
```

Just add the below code in your activity:

```
etPassword.requestFocus();
```

Or

You can do it from XML:

Just add the below attribute for the password EditText.

```
android:focusable=true
```